# Jquery + Append + PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, append

My code (index.html)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            $.get("load_txt.php", { 'var1': 4, 'var2' : 52},
                function(data){ $('#msg').append(data); }, "json");
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
<p id='msg'></p>
```

My code (load_txt.php)

```
<?php
$var1 = $_GET['var1'];
$var2 = $_GET['var2'];

    $data = "var1= " . $var1 . " " . "var2= " . $var2;

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

It doesnt work, nothing is showing in #msg. Can you see some mistake? if yes, please answere, thx :)

Comment: none. console is clean

Comment: You should check what returns your php script, i guess an error. And btw, sending a request each second without waiting for any previous one to complete is a no-go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not actually returning JSON. You're running a string through `json_encode` with no key, which is just giving you back a string. This is then returned to jQuery which is expecting JSON so is most likely throwing an error trying to deserialise a plain string.

To fix this, change your PHP code to actually return JSON:

```
echo json_encode(array('var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2));
```

And amend your jQuery to read from the deserialised object:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $.get("load_txt.php", { 
        'var1': 4, 
        'var2': 52
    }, function(data) { 
        $('#msg').append(data.var1 + ' ' + data.var2); 
    }, "json");
}, 1000);
```

Also note that making AJAX requests using `setInterval` is not a great idea, as if the requests take longer than the interval to complete they will stack up. It's better to use `setTimeout` and make the new request when the previous one has completed:

```
function makeRequest() {
    $.get("load_txt.php", { 
        'var1': 4, 
        'var2': 52
    }, function(data) { 
        $('#msg').append(data.var1 + ' ' + data.var2); 
        setTimeout(makeRequest, 1000); // on success
    }, "json");
}
makeRequest(); // on load
```

Comment: i absolutelly dont know why, but it still doesnt work. Screenshots: http://imgur.com/a/IcqV0

Comment: Could you please also check the 'network' tab of the console to see what the state of the request is.

Answer (score -1):

It's just a syntax error:

This code works ok:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $.get("load_txt.php", { 'var1': 4, 'var2' : 52},
            function(data){ $('#msg').append(data); }, "json");
    }, 1000);
});
```

; Note, this(**) piece need to be deleted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $.get("load_txt.php", { 'var1': 4, 'var2' : 52},
            function(data){ $('#msg').append(data); }, "json");
        **});**
    }, 1000);
});
```